# При создании анимации не работают переходы по ссылкам

Tags: css3, html

Когда я создаю анимацию, у меня не переходит по ссылкам (точнее он вообще не работает, а анимация все гуд). Когда забираю content, ссылка работает, а анимация - нет.

```
.blue_animation {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #28ABE1;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.blue_animation:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #28ABE1 solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
}

.blue_animation:hover:before, .blue_animation:focus:before, .blue_animation:active:before {
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
}
```

Comment: @headache, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Больше информации пожалуйста. Где ссылка находится, что за блок conent и куда Вы его забираете?

Answer (score 1):

Без свойства content псевдоэлемент не показывается, поэтому не работает анимация. Накидал в JSFiddle ваш пример - у меня всё работает, в том числе и переход по ссылке. [Вот тут ваш пример, можете убедиться](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1frr5k/1/)